# Search folders and return files containing specific keyword and most recent version

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search a folder for files that contain a specified keyword, then return the file name, last modified date and path to an Excel worksheet.

For example

```
REF     FolderPath      REF   FileName   LastModified   FilePath  
Apple   C:\Fruits           
Kale    C:\Vegetables           
Spinach C:\Vegetables
```

I will have keywords and folder paths in column A and B. The folder called "Fruits" contains a file named "Apple_v5.xls". I would search for the keyword "Apple", then return the name, most recent version and file path (Col D, E, F) to the same spreadsheet. Col C will list the keywords again in Col A. Macro will also keep going down the list of keywords until it reaches the end.

This is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, lr As Long, fPath As String
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")
    lstRw = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=sh.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious,                 MatchCase:=False).Row
    Set rng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lstRw)

    For i = 1 To 100

        fPath = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value

        If Right(fPath, 1) <> "\" Then
            fPath = fPath & "\"
        End If

        fWb = Dir(fPath & "*.*")
        x = 2
        Do While fWb <> ""
            For Each c In rng
                If InStr(LCase(fWb), LCase(c.Value)) > 0 Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x) = fWb
                    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                    Set f = fs.GetFile(fWb)
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & x) = f.DateLastModified
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F" & x) = f.Path
                    Worksheets("sheet2").Range("D" & x) = c.Value
                    Worksheets("sheet2").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(x, 2), Address:=f.Path
                    Columns("A:D").AutoFit
                    Set fs = Nothing
                    Set f = Nothing
                    x = x + 1
                End If
            Next
            fWb = Dir
        Loop
        Set sh = Nothing
        Set rng = Nothing

    Next i

    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few issues with some of the code/layout here. Without essentially re-writing most of the macro for you, here's the approach you can use.

---Obtain the range of cells that have your keyword (you do this already with your `rng`)

---Set your row counter (you already use the `x` variable to do this)

---Loop through each cell in the range (you do this already using the `for each c in rng` code)

Then within that loop...

---Get the filepath from the B column (you do this already when you set your `fPath` variable)

---Search the folder for the first file with the keyword using the following code

```
fwb = Dir(fPath & c.Value & ".*")
```

This takes your REF value and inserts it in the directory path. the * in ".*" states that you want it to return any file type (e.g. Apple.txt, Apple.pdf, Apple.mp3)

-- If the file was found, then populate the date last modified, path, name of file, and hyperlink (all of which you know how to do already as indicated by the rest of the code)

-- Reset your file and filesystemobject variables (`f` and `fs`)

Finally, outside of your loop, you can reset your other variables (i.e. `sh`, `rng`) Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I made the above changes but it didnt work. Right now it is just grabbing all the files in the folder and ignore my keyword. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I rewrote my answer as there more needed than just the updates I provided before. The edited answer will cover everything now